# How can we randomize duty of an employee

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to allow duty in three shift

There is the following constraint :

```
1st shift will have 5 employee 
>2nd shift will have 3 employee
3rd shift will have 2 employee
```

if a person is allotted duty in any shift he will not be allowed duty further two shift. ex. if Mr. X is allotted duty in the 2nd shift on 3rd Aug then he will neither get duty in the 3rd shift on 3rd Aug nor in the 1st shift on 4th Aug

I have used `rand()` function to randomly select the employee. I am facing a problem with constraint 4. i.e. how can I make it sure that an employee who has been allotted duty in the 1st shift will not get allotted in 2nd or 3rd shift

My MySQL query is :

```
SELECT * FROM `employee` ORDER BY rand()
```

Comment: Try in php and share with us

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: how are you storing the shift assignment detail?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a difficult problem to solve in SQL, but if I was going to attempt it, I would probably start with randomizing the employees...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employees;

CREATE TABLE employees 
(employee_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO employees VALUES
(101),(102),(103),(104),(105),(106),(107),(108),(109),(110);

SELECT employee_id,@i:=@i+1 i FROM (SELECT employee_id FROM employees ORDER BY RAND()) x,(SELECT @i:=0) vars;
+-------------+------+
| employee_id | i    |
+-------------+------+
|         108 |    1 |
|         109 |    2 |
|         110 |    3 |
|         103 |    4 |
|         105 |    5 |
|         106 |    6 |
|         102 |    7 |
|         104 |    8 |
|         107 |    9 |
|         101 |   10 |
+-------------+------+
```

Now, as long as we have at least 3 days' worth of employees (5+3+2=10), we can just cycle through the list, and know that every employee will always have at least two consecutive rest days between each work day.

Here's a thought about the other aspect of the problem...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS shifts;

CREATE TABLE shifts 
(shift_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,shift_size INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO shifts VALUES
(1,5),(2,3),(3,2),(4,3),(5,2);

SELECT shift_id
     , ROUND(COALESCE(@j:=@prev+1,1),0) range_start
     , range_end, @prev:=range_end 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , SUM(y.shift_size) range_end 
         FROM shifts x 
         JOIN shifts y 
           ON y.shift_id <= x.shift_id 
        GROUP 
           BY x.shift_id
     ) b
     , ( SELECT @j:=1,@prev:=null) vars
 ORDER 
    BY shift_id;
+----------+-------------+-----------+------------------+
| shift_id | range_start | range_end | @prev:=range_end |
+----------+-------------+-----------+------------------+
|        1 |           1 |         5 |                5 |
|        2 |           6 |         8 |                8 |
|        3 |           9 |        10 |               10 |
|        4 |          11 |        13 |               13 |
|        5 |          14 |        15 |               15 |
+----------+-------------+-----------+------------------+
```

So now you have an employee sequence id and a range within which those ids can fall. The range is larger than the list of employees, so you have to use the size of the employees table as the modulus of the range.

```
 SELECT a.shift_id
      , MOD(a.range_start-1,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees))+1 range_start
      , MOD(a.range_end-1,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees))+1 range_end
   FROM
      ( SELECT shift_id
      , ROUND(COALESCE(@j:=@prev+1,1),0) range_start
      , range_end, @prev:=range_end
   FROM
      ( SELECT x.*
             , SUM(y.shift_size) range_end
          FROM shifts x
          JOIN shifts y
            ON y.shift_id <= x.shift_id
         GROUP
            BY x.shift_id
      ) b
      , ( SELECT @j:=1,@prev:=null) vars
  ORDER
     BY shift_id
     ) a
   ORDER BY shift_id;
+----------+-------------+-----------+
| shift_id | range_start | range_end |
+----------+-------------+-----------+
|        1 |           1 |         5 |
|        2 |           6 |         8 |
|        3 |           9 |        10 |
|        4 |           1 |         3 |
|        5 |           4 |         5 |
+----------+-------------+-----------+
```

I guess I can leave the final step as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score -1):

Since you have not provided much detail, it is hard to figure out how you are storing the information in the database. I guess the following query would suit your case:

```
SELECT * FROM employee e
WHERE e.employee_id NOT IN (
                            SELECT es.employee_id FROM emp_shifts es
                            WHERE shift IN (...)
                            )
ORDER BY RAND()
```

I assume you are storing shift allotment in emp_shifts table.
... are the last 2 shifts you want to exclude.

Comment: Please provide a sqlfiddle so I can provide a better solution.